# Probabilities for computers decision in ML?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Phrased this quite badly, but what I am trying to ask is say how can I display percentage of confidence in predicting something with a classification algorithm? I am using Scikit-learn.

Say that I am trying to identify whether something is an apple or orange based on texture and weight:

```
#Features:  0 = "bumpy" 1 = "smooth"
#Labels:    0 = apple 1 = orange
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]

# We will be using a Decision Tree in this instance
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([[160, 0]]))
```

So with predicting the `[160, 0]`, based on the pattern, we and the computer will predict that this is most likely to be an orange. **Is there a way with Scikit-learn that I can predict the confidence the computer has in returning either a 1 or a 0?** This is especially important when I have more parameters in the feature vector.

Comment: Maybe just [read the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html).

Comment: @BenAubin That makes sense. I don't really know much about neural networks, but is there a way I can run this sort of similar code on a neural network?

Comment: @BenAubin I'm afraid you're (quite) wrong. Check the docs and my answer below.

Comment: @lollercoaster huh. Thanks for letting me know and catching that.

Comment: no problem. decision trees are cool!

Comment: @rmahesh about using a neural network, you should be able to train it with an output neuron for every option, then train it so when every output is 1 when the option is correct. The network will output probabilities for each option and you pick the “correct” one based on the highest score.

Comment: Decision trees are very cool, especially as it’s very easy to understand how a specific one works.

Comment: @BenAubin for neural net, you can do better. you'd only want a single output neuron. Since it's a two class (binary) problem, the probability would be the probability of class = 'apple', so the converse is the complement (or 1 - P(apple))

Comment: @lollercoaster yeah, that would be better, but it would leave little room for adding other options - what if I put in a pear? Is it a 50% chance of being an apple? What about a random screenshot from my camera roll by accident? That only works if you’re sure every option is a apple or a pear.

Comment: Uh, no. Supervised models can't (and aren't meant to) generalize to classes they have never seen, that's not the point of them. You can have an "unknown" class, but that would simply be the third class. In the case of three classes, yes you'd have 3 output neurons. But for binary you only need 1 output (and in fact if you had 2 you'd notice that they were redundant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

Just use the [`predict_proba(X)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba) function (instead of `predict()`).

```
probability = clf.predict_proba([[160, 0]])
```

Certain classifiers in scikit have the ability to do this, others don't.

In the case of `DecisionTreeClassifier`, the model, when asked for a probability of a given class, will give the fraction of elements in the training set that were the same class in that particular "leaf".

A leaf in a decision tree is a set of conditions (rules) that represents a path down the tree.

For example for the example `[0, 160]` where they represent `[x1, x2]`, the rule might have been

```
if x1 < 10:
    if x2 > 150:
        # in our training set of `n` examples, 100 fell under 
        # this rule set. 75 of them were apple, and 25 were orange - thus:
        probability = [0.75, 0.25]  # P(apple) = .75, P(orange) = .25
```

And of course in a binary classification case (two classes) scikit returns both, but your really only need one or the other because the probabilities are complementary (1 - .75 = .25).

Check out the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) to learn more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! After reading through the documentation, I am a bit confused on the parameters. I do understand that the probability will be for a path down the tree. Is there any way that I can get the probability in comparison to the entire tree? Because when I ran this, I got [0, 1], which I have no idea what that means, even after looking at the documentation. And what would it mean if I was to get [1,0] as an answer if I was running another program and using the predict_proba?

Comment: Nope, if you run the code you have above you'll get `[1]`. That means the tree has estimated 100% (1) probability that the example in question is of class[0], which in your case is `apple`.

Comment: So if I got [0, 1] that means that the tree estimated 100% probability that it is label 0?

Comment: Ah, you mean with `predict_proba()`. Not quite, you're close -  `[0, 1]` means that `P(class[0]) = 0` and `P(class[1]=1)`. Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: Ahh I see so if I'd saying 0% probability for class 0 and 100% probability for class 1? Just want to make sure I understand properly.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Okay thanks! If I was to go about experimenting with neural networks from where I'm at now, where would you recommend me starting?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that. Unless you're doing things with images in which you'd need the net to use high level features and abstractions, just use simple linear / tree / probabilistic scikit classification models. You'll be far better off and won't use models too complex for the simple data you have. But if you are doing things with images, I'd suggest Tensorflow, perhaps with Keras if you're a bit squeamish about linear algebra.